# Bool Tool slice function

Tags: tools

Bool tool slice function not working the way I want it to it's removing parts of the mesh instead of just slicing.

How I want it to work:
[image][image]

How it works:
[image]

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=62WSoYQj" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/62WSoYQj/)

Comment: Have you applied the scale to both parts before trying to slice?

Comment: Yeah i tried that getting the same result

Comment: It's difficult to see which part you're actually trying to slice as there are so many separate objects, but if it's the bit I think the geometry is quite ugly with extra edges and vertices which may well be confusing the boolean. Try isolating just the part you're trying to slice with the slash key on the numpad and look at it in edit mode. You can probably dissolve most of the edges on the sides for a start.